# Is it safe to discard HttpResponseMessage without reading the content?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using `HttpClient` to get an `HttpResponseMessage` object. Depending on the headers, I don't actually care about the response body so I don't want to read the body content, just discard it.

I've seen a few examples online that read through the response body even in scenarios where the content bytes are immediately discarded and I'm trying to understand if this is necessary or not. For example, I found this GitHub [gist](https://gist.github.com/joelverhagen/3be85bc0d5733756befa#file-redirectinghandler-cs-L124) that does that, line 124:

```
if (DownloadContentOnRedirect && response.Content != null)
{
    await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
}
```

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri))
{
    var response = await (httpClient.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None));

    // Some code here related to the work being done but not 
    // touching the response.

    if (!CheckSomeHeaders(response))
    {
        // Response may have large body. Do not read, discard.
        response.Dispose(); // Is this correct / enough?
    }
    else
    {
        // Do some other stuff. Response will be returned to
        // caller and caller is responsible for handling it.
    }
}
```

I'd like to avoid reading the response body if I already know I'm not interested (the body may be long). *Note, that `response` is not inside a `using` block on purpose; the response may be returned in some cases to the caller.*

Is the above gist a necessary step or is it safe to just call Dispose() to avoid resource leaks. I cannot think of a situation where reading the content would be necessary but perhaps I'm overlooking something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the above gist a necessary step

No.

> is it safe to just call `Dispose()` to avoid resource leaks.

Yes.

But is most cases there will be no need to. It will be disposed when it goes out of scope if refactored to be wrapped in a `using`

Comment: Thank you - this is what I suspected. My `response` is not inside a `using` block on purpose - sometimes the response gets returned to the caller and the caller decides what to do with it. Sometimes my own code discards it early and continues on.